# where can I find A5 paper size in word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I'm using Word 2013 and I want to set my paper size to A5 but It seems there isn't such an option! Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a custom size.

(ribbon) -> Page Layout -> Size: More Paper Sizes..., Paper size: Custom

The size should be half of A4:

```
A4: 210   * 297mm  (8.27"  * 11.69")
A5: 148.5 * 210mm  (5.845" *  8.27")
```

Hopefully, your printer would understand it...